# ¿Cómo sacar el texto de una etiqueta en vb.net?

Tags: html, vb.net

He creado una aplicación en Vb.net que hace su trabajo perfectamente, me he quedado en una parte donde no sé como hacer para extraer el valor que hay en una etiqueta del tipo `<b>0</b>`.

Este es el codigo de la página:

```
<div style="font-size:18px;">
      You can only claim <b>72</b> times a day.
      <br>
      You have already claimed <b>0</b> times today.
</div>
```

Lo que necesito capturas es el valor de la segunda linea **`<b>0</b>`** Gracias si me pueden ayudar

Comment: este valor lo necesitas en el cliente o en el servidor?

Comment: Buen día compañero, Quieres colocar un valor dentro de esa etiqueta? O quieres obtener el valor que está en ella y almacenarlo?

Saludos cordiales

Comment: Hola  Fran Islas NECESITO MOSTRAR ESE VALOR EN UN LABEL EN MI FORM.

Comment: Edwin Vasquez Amigo necesito el valor de esa etiqueta y mostrarlo en un label en mi form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has de Utilizar javascript

```js
    function VerDato(){
      var Dato = document.getElementById("Dato").innerHTML;
      alert(Dato);
    }
```

```html
    <div style="font-size:18px;">
          You can only claim <b>72</b> times a day.
          <br>
          You have already claimed <b><div id="Dato">0</div></b> times today.
          <input type="button" onclick="VerDato()" value="Obtener Dato" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, no uso js, ya que por alguna razón navegador de mi aplicacion no me reconoce el js. lo que queria era alguna funcion que pueda llamar luego que la página web este cargada.